# Joining return tables from sql functions which have same name temp tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, execution, temp-tables

I need to join return tables from multiple SQL functions. In those sql functions, they use a bunch of temp tables with the same name (such as tmp_result, tmp_datetime, etc.). Within each sql functions, there are statements to drop the temp tables if exists before creating the temp tables. When I join the return tables from those sql functions, do the joining part be evaluated sequentially? Use the generic query below as an example, do I need to worry that tmp_result table created by my_function_1 be dropped by drop table statement in my_function_2 pre-maturely? I did some test and the results looked fine. But I'd like to know if there are potential issues. Thanks.

```
select a.*, b.*
from my_function_1(1,2,3) a
    join my_function_2(4,5,6) b on a.id=b.id
order by 1;
```

Comment: You should be fine, but if it worries you use **different** temp table names.

Comment: Wouldn't these calls be considered the same session?  If so, I think this would be an issue.  Should be easy enough to test though.

Comment: @Belayer, thanks. I can make efforts to make sure not to use same temp table names. But generally speaking, it is not always be possible to make sure no same name temp tables if we rely on sql functions created by others.

Comment: @Andrew, based on my test, the two calls are same session. If the execution evaluates my_function_1 first and only after that it starts to evaluate my_function_2, then I think I am fine. but I am not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By some testing, I think the sql functions are evaluated/called in sequence. Only after the previous one is done, the next one will be called. in my test, I used clock_timestamp() at the beginning and end of each sql function to monitor the invoking time and sequence. I made one sql function to take long time to finish and move it around in the join sequence. All my tests showed that the sql functions were evaluated in sequence. So even with same temp table names in different sql functions, it should be fine.